# Is there a command to undo git-flow feature start?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm inexperienced with git-flow.

Is there a command to undo `git-flow feature start`?

Comment: Always remember that Git flow commands are really just shortcuts for a series of regular Git commands. In the case of `feature start`, it's literally just switching to your development branch and starting a new branch. Understanding the commands that git-flow uses lets you very easily abandon the tool (which is pretty poor) and continue to use the workflow, which is much more valuable.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Since git-flow just wraps regular git functionality, how about simply deleting the new branch (assuming you have no changes in there you want saved)?

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git branch -d feature/your-feature-name-here
```

Answer (score 64):

Or just use git-flow:

```
git flow feature delete your-feature-branch
```

Note that the `feature/` prefix is omitted when using this command

Comment: My copy of Git-flow doesn't include 'delete' as an option for the 'git flow feature' command.

Answer (score -3):

```
git hf feature cancel -f
```

Use `git hf help` and `git hf feature help` to see the possibilities.

Comment: `git hf` is actually a part of [HubFlow](http://datasift.github.io/gitflow/index.html), which is not a part of the standard git flow.

Comment: Neither is `git-flow` which the OP uses.